# Order by Counts in a Group

Tags: sql, group-by, count, sql-order-by

I have the data which looks like below:

```
group   resource    count
A          X          5
A          Y          8
A          Z          2
B          E          8
B          F          10
B          G          2
```

I want to order the data in a way that the group comes on the top having highest sum of count using SQL statement. Such as:

```
group   resource    count
B          F          10
B          E          8
B          G          2
A          Y          8
A          X          5
A          Z          2
```

I am avoiding using multiple select statements too. Any help for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a window function to sum your count and order by that. Your DBMS was not listed, so might need some minor tweaks to syntax, but I think this should work for most DBMS

```
SELECT [Group]
    ,[Resource]
    ,[Count]
    ,TotalCountOfGroup = SUM([Count]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group])
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY TotalCountOfGroup DESC,[Count] DESC
```

Or if you need to exclude the TotalCount column, can wrap it in a CTE

```
WITH cte_YourData AS (
    SELECT [Group],[Resource],[Count]
        ,TotalCountOfGroup = SUM([Count]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group])
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT [Group],[Resource],[Count]
FROM cte_YourData
ORDER BY TotalCountOfGroup DESC,[Count] DESC
```